# tableview won't scroll when subview of main view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

i have a MainViewController that when a tab bar button on the bottom of view is clicked, it populates the central main view in MainViewController with another view controller called dataViewController via a segue. In dataViewController it has a UITableView that populates from an array. I am missing something simple i think because when i give dataViewcontroller initial scene view controller, it runs fine and i can roll through the table and all its cells/content. As soon as i make MainViewController the initial scene view controller, i click data button, it changes view populates the tableview. I can select individual cells and they highlight, but when i try to roll through the table it crashes the simulator and does give what looks like a reason?

MainViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak,nonatomic)UIViewController *currentViewController;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mainView;

@end
```

MainViewController.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize currentViewController;
@synthesize mainView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"location"] == NULL) [defaults setObject:@"Spring Hill" forKey:@"location"];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"temperature"] == NULL) [defaults setObject:@"Celsius" forKey:@"temperature"];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"windSpeed"] == NULL)   [defaults setObject:@"kph" forKey:@"windSpeed"];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"wingType"] == NULL)    [defaults setObject:@"Paraglider" forKey:@"wingType"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"graphSegue" sender:self];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.navigationItem.title = [defaults objectForKey:@"location"];
}

@end
```

CustomTabBarSegue.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTabBarSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

@end
```

CustomTabBarSeque.m

```
#import "CustomTabBarSegue.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation CustomTabBarSegue

- (void) perform {
    MainViewController *currentView = (MainViewController *)self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destView = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;
    for(UIView *view in currentView.mainView.subviews){
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    currentView.currentViewController = destView;
    [currentView.mainView addSubview:destView.view];
}

@end
```

I'm not sure if it is something on the storyboard i have not ticked/selected or some inadequate code i have?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the .header file you have to specify that this view will conform to UITableView protocols like this:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Though no UITableView seems declared in your code. You have to declare it as a property, not just put it in the storyboard and set its delegate and datasource in your viewDidLoad method like this:

```
self.myTableView.delegate = self;
self.myTableView.datasource = self;
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  the tableview is load through the view controller dataViewController, which is where delegate and the datasource are loaded. if i added the above to the main view controller it would expect a table view to be in the MainViewController ?? dataViewController works on it is as the only view controller, but loaded through segue crashes.